# Layouting personal developer home page

Tags: navigation, layout, page-layout

I am stuck at layouting personal home page which intended to present me as software developer and R&D man.

I am definitely don't want geeky home page like famous https://www.jwz.org/ (scrolling green hexes on black screen as if you in 70') or typical professor at campus like [http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Euno/) (with gifs as if you in 95').

Black on white, with some styling/typography, centered, with mobile view in mind it should guide reader about me, my projects, my articles, tips, cooking recipes, cats photos, my music scores etc.

I don't understand how to provide information on the page (which is simply links to actual information).

Should it be a links with short names like `tips`,`blog`,`hacking`,`cooking` or long like `this is my tech blog`, `my grandma recipes` or short with explanation text like `My [link]2048 game[/link] AI implementation`?

Should links be organized in single line or list or grouped into related sections?

Should I have TOC or sidebar or force reader to scroll down?

I made a sketch where I group links into 3 cols for wide screen and it looks bad and amateur (layout, we are not discussing colors).

[image]

Should I mark borders of sections and active regions or use just plain text, blue links and list circles?

Another my page I think have nice look:

[image]

but it doesn't scale well if say I have 10 grouping categories and 50 links.

Answer (score 1):

This forum isn't intended for critiquing or designing a specific site. That is too broad a topic, and to small a target to apply it to. We're here to discuss specific problems/solutions that apply to many places.

In that respect, your most relevant question would be:

---

### Should I use long or short labels for links?

This depends on the type of link it is. If it's in a menu, pretty short. If it's in a tag cloud, short. If it's a link to a specific article or page, a bit longer and descriptive.

From the mockup I can't quite tell what you're going for, but you could have boxes that contain all 3:

> MY RANTS
>
> ---
>
> Why Emacs is a nightmare
>
> How to make soggy broccoli
>
> What makes VIM terrible
>
> My 'top' 5 grandma recipes
>
> Notepad++? No, Bad, --
>
> ---
>
> TAGS: cooking, coding, contempt